# HOW TO BUILD A COMPLEX ARGUMENT FOR A SOAP FUNCTION WITH PYTHON AND ZEEP

Tags: python-3.x, magento, soap, zeep

I'm connecting to a SOAP v2 webservice with Python3.7 and zeep. One call to create an object requires a complex structure to be passed as an argument. This is the WSDL for the call and it's arguments:

```
   <message name="catalogProductAttributeAddOptionRequest">
    <part name="sessionId" type="xsd:string"/>
    <part name="attribute" type="xsd:string"/>
    <part name="data" type="typens:catalogProductAttributeOptionEntityToAdd"/>
    </message>

    <complexType name="catalogProductAttributeOptionEntityToAdd">
    <all>
    <element name="label" type="typens:catalogProductAttributeOptionLabelArray"/>
    <element name="order" type="xsd:int"/>
    <element name="is_default" type="xsd:int"/>
    </all>
    </complexType>

    <complexType name="catalogProductAttributeOptionLabelArray">
    <complexContent>
    <restriction base="soapenc:Array">
    <attribute ref="soapenc:arrayType" wsdl:arrayType="typens:catalogProductAttributeOptionLabelEntity[]"/>
    </restriction>
    </complexContent>
    </complexType>

    <complexType name="catalogProductAttributeOptionLabelEntity">
    <all>
    <element name="store_id" type="typens:ArrayOfString"/>
    <element name="value" type="xsd:string"/>
    </all>
    </complexType>
```

The problem that I have is how to pass the "data" argument to the function in Python 3 using zeep. I have an example on how to do this in php:

```
$label = array (
array(
"store_id" => array("0"),
"value" => "some random data"
)
);
$data = array(
"label" => $label,
"order" => "10",
"is_default" => "1"
);
$orders = $client->catalogProductAttributeAddOption($session, $attributeCode, $data);
```

This code is supossed to work altough I haven't tested it. So, the $data structure should have the equivalent in a python dict as this one:

```
data=[
    {
        "label": [
            [
                {
                    "store_id":["0"],
                    "value":"some random data"
                }
            ]
        ],
        "order":10,
        "is_default":1
    }
]
```

And I call the function this way:

```
client.service.catalogProductAttributeAddOption(sessionId=sessionid,attribute="manufacturer",data=data)
```

If I do that I receive this exception:

```
TypeError: Any element received object of type 'list', expected lxml.etree._Element or builtins.dict or zeep.objects.catalogProductAttributeOptionLabelEntity
See http://docs.python-zeep.org/en/master/datastructures.html#any-objects for more information
```

So I start investigating about the Any elements and I discover a way of casting parts of the structure to its type in the wsdl namespace, so I do this:

```
entity={
            "store_id":["0"],
            "value":"some random data"
        }

catalogProductAttributeOptionLabelEntity=client.get_type('ns0:catalogProductAttributeOptionLabelEntity')

retyped_entity=catalogProductAttributeOptionLabelEntity(entity)



label=[  
      retyped_entity
]

catalogProductAttributeOptionLabelArray = client.get_type('ns0:catalogProductAttributeOptionLabelArray')

retyped_label=catalogProductAttributeOptionLabelArray(label)

data=[
    {
        "label": retyped_label,
        "order":10,
        "is_default":1
    }
]

catalogProductAttributeOptionEntityToAdd=client.get_type('ns0:catalogProductAttributeOptionEntityToAdd')

retyped_data=catalogProductAttributeOptionEntityToAdd(data)

client.service.catalogProductAttributeAddOption(sessionId=sessionid,attribute="manufacturer",data=retyped_data)
```

And then, I got this error:

```
ValidationError: 'Missing element for Any'
```

I've investigated and it seems that this error comes when the structure is not in the format that is required... I mean, like if the dict I wrote before were not equivalent to the php structure written before, and if the new structure created with castings to the required types were not in the structure required.

At this point I'm stucked and I don't know how to go on. Any expert eye can see where is my error?

By the way, if this is solved, this also answer the question "How to write a manufacturer in Magento 1 using SOAP v2 webservice with Python and Zeep". Question which is not solved anywhere.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I can't help with the details of your situation, but I would try to make the correct request in soapUI at the beginning. https://www.soapui.org/

Answer (score 0):

I've been able to execute the function by using this structure:

```
    ArrayOfString=client.get_type('ns0:ArrayOfString')

    data=[
        {
            "label":[{
                "store_id":ArrayOfString(["0"]),
                "value":"some random data"
            }],
            "order":"10",
            "is_default":"1"
        }
    ]

    client.service.catalogProductAttributeAddOption(sessionId=sessionid,attribute="manufacturer",data=data)
```

I choosed a general title because my question was about trying to find out how to convert the wsdl structure needed by the function into a python dict, but this question solves a very particular question which is more interesting, and that is: "How to write a manufacturer in the magento soap V2 webservice using Python 3 and zeep".